# IOS UIWebview displaying Text files

Tags: ios, uiwebview, text-files

I am having issue with character encoding for displaying text files in UIWebView. I am using utf8 encoding but if i create a text file using ansi format then if characters appears as boxes. Is there any way to generalize this for all text files